# Windows 10 installation failure on Ryzen 9 cpu

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, windows-installation, amd-ryzen

I am trying to install windows 10 on my computer that I had recently upgraded to the ryzen 9 cpu with. My system has a 1tb nvme ssd (hp 920) and 2 4tb hdds (a barracuda and an ironwolf) and I do not use raid. I want to install a 2.5 tb windows partition on the barracuda drive and leave the rest for my primary os, fedora. For starters, I have installed windows on the computer with a ryzen 1700x in order to install the bios updates to the motherboard (gigabyte aorus x470 gaming 5) and got it bios version f41, so that it could now be compatible with the ryzen 9 cpu.

After that I installed the ryzen 9 cpu and when I tried to boot the computer, windows BSOD instantly, which I was fine with because it was a fresh install anyway. So I used the USB that I had made to install windows previously to reinstall it thinking maybe I just had to use the new spu on the install, but that didn't work, still got BSOD and was told the install didn't work. I then tried to look online and saw that the 2019 May windows update broke windows on certain ryzen cpus so I tried to install the 2018 october update version (I got the iso from the microsoft website and used rufus to make a bootable usb drive), but BSOD again.

I read a little more about the issue and it was apparently due to issues with the nvme and raid drivers and that it would work if you installed the updated drivers at the windows install, so I tried to do that. However, I don't use raid, so the only driver the windows installer would say was compatible with my system was the nvme bottom device driver and since I didn't use raid, I thought it would be fine and that it would be a bad idea to install the raid drivers. However again windows BSOD on me again. So then I installed every driver that AMD provided for raid and nvme disregarded compatibility, but that didn't work either. Also I checked the motherboard to see if any leds that indicated any issues lit up, and none of them did, and so my hardware must be fine then. How the hell am I supposed to install windows?

EDIT: I got the nvidia RAID drivers here and it also provided the instructions to install them: https://www.amd.com/en/support/chipsets/amd-socket-tr4/x399

I read about the May update break here: https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/windows-10-may-2019-update-cuasing-issues-for-some-amd-ryzen-pcsfix-in-this-item.html

Comment: Windows 10 supports NVMe drives out of the box.  It might be helpful if you disconnect any drive other than the system drive.  I suspect you have a boot order issue, I had the same issue, until I did exactly that.

Comment: @Ramhound So I am trying install windows on a secondary drive and not a primary drive. Before with the 1700x cpu this wasn't a problem, but with the 3900x cpu, I blue screen. I'm following the same steps as before from when it worked, so I don't believe boot order is the problem

Comment: The issues outlined in that particular article have already been fixed.  RAID drivers shouldn't be required to run in the configuration you describe.

Comment: @Ramhound, so should I remove every drive except for the hdd I want to install windows on?